# Looping through 2 columns to find start and end point to insert formula in another column

Tags: vba

I'm relatively new to VBA and was hoping to get some advice on my problem.

I have three columns. 
Column A is my start signal, Column B is my end signal, the signals are marked by the value "1". 
Column C is where I want a formula to be inserted.

I'm looking for some code that loops through column A and B to find the start and end points of inserting a formula in column C, and to repeat this process until the end of column A.

Something like below. 
Would really appreciate any help on this!

Thank you xx

```
    A    B    C            D                
1        
2   1         01/02/2018   01/02/2018
3             02/02/2018   01/02/2018
4             03/02/2018   01/02/2018
5             04/02/2018   01/02/2018
6             05/02/2018   01/02/2018
7       1     06/02/2018   01/02/2018
8             07/02/2018
9             08/02/2018
10            09/02/2018
11  1         10/02/2018   10/02/2018
12            11/02/2018   10/02/2018
13            12/02/2018   10/02/2018
14            13/02/2018   10/02/2018
15      1     14/02/2018   10/02/2018
16            15/02/2018
17            16/02/2018
18            17/02/2018
19  1         18/02/2018   18/02/2018
20  1         19/02/2018   18/02/2018
21  1         20/02/2018   18/02/2018
```

Comment: There is no picture attached. Also, if you would like help solving a problem please post any code that you have tried.

Comment: Thanks Miles! Its my first ever post, just managed to add the picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted your picture and added a block with data.  People here prefer not to have to click on links to understand your question.

EDIT

Normally people here will object, if you change your question.  It means that previously given answers no longer match the question, and that is unfair to people who have answered in good faith.  The accepted practice is to accept an answer to the first question, and ask a second one.  It is OK to refer to a previous question.  But since I was the only one who answered, and you are a newbie, I am being nice and altering my answer:

The following should do what you want:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim endRow As Integer
Dim doFormula As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim formulaText As String

    doFormula = False
    formulaText = ""

    endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 1 To endRow

        If Cells(i, 1) = 1 And formulaText = "" Then
            formulaText = "=" + Cells(i, 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        End If
        If Cells(i, 1) = 1 Or doFormula Then
            Cells(i, 4).Formula = formulaText
            doFormula = True
        End If
        If Cells(i, 1) <> 1 And Cells(i, 2) = 1 Then
            doFormula = False
            formulaText = ""
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

By way of explanation, Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row gives you the last used row in column A.  You might need to amend this later to use column B instead.  It then loops through the rows until the last one to see if the formula needs adding.  I set a Boolean value as false to begin with, so that any initial empty rows are ignored, and then the flag gets unset when it hits something in B.  Cells(x, y).Address gives the A1 notation of the cells address; you can get relative or absolute addresses according to the parameters.  The requirement that formulaText should be empty when resetting it, means that the 18th February value is repeated, even though the row has 1 in the a column.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan! Let me give this a try and really appreciate your time helping me on this.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I just checked and it does exactly what I needed, thank you! I'm now facing a new issue and have edited my original question: The formula I'd like to insert in column D is the value of the first row of column C each time column A = "1". I understand how the R1C1 notation works, but have not managed to find a way to 'absolute a relative reference' each time Cells(i,1) = 1. If you have some insight on that it will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!