# Looping a column and inserting a formula that has relative reference, but made absolute/fixed each time the formula is inserted

Tags: excel, vba

This is a follow up from a [previous question which has been kindly solved by Jonathan Willcock.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925320/looping-through-2-columns-to-find-start-and-end-point-to-insert-formula-in-anoth)

He has helped me with a solution to loop through 2 columns and insert a formula in another column where applicable.

However, my problem now is that the formula I want to insert (in column D below), should be the first corresponding row in column C each time the start is 'triggered'. ie, I'd like column D to show the trigger date each time the loop is triggered.

What this looks like is:

```
    A    B    C            D                
1             31/01/2018
2   1         01/02/2018   01/02/2018
3             02/02/2018   01/02/2018
4             03/02/2018   01/02/2018
5             04/02/2018   01/02/2018
6             05/02/2018   01/02/2018
7       1     06/02/2018   01/02/2018
8             07/02/2018
9             08/02/2018
10            09/02/2018
11  1         10/02/2018   10/02/2018
12            11/02/2018   10/02/2018
13            12/02/2018   10/02/2018
14            13/02/2018   10/02/2018
15      1     14/02/2018   10/02/2018
16            15/02/2018
17            16/02/2018
18            17/02/2018
19  1         18/02/2018   18/02/2018
20            19/02/2018   18/02/2018
21            20/02/2018   18/02/2018
```

Column A is the start trigger, column B is the end trigger, and column D is where I want the formula inserted, which is the date of the trigger.

This is a modification of the code he wrote, which finds the start and stop point of inserting a formula in anothr column:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim endRow As Integer
Dim doFormula As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

    doFormula = False

    endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To endRow
        If Cells(i, 1) = 1 Or doFormula Then
            Cells(i, 4) = "[formula that returns trigger date of that incident]"
            doFormula = True
        End If
        If Cells(i, 1) <> 1 And Cells(i, 2) = 1 Then
            doFormula = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I was wondering if anyone might have some insight on solving this issue? 
I understand how to use relative vs absolute RC reference, but not sure how to 'fix' a relative value each time the loop is triggered.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Do you just want D to equal C when there is a 1 in A?

Comment: Btw it would be good if you could accept Jonathan's answer as it helped you.